# TFS2010 Build failing -- Read permission required

Tags: build-process

I recently moved a project from TFS2008 to 2010, and I'm having trouble getting the 2010 build scripts to work. I managed to make the script run using the the upgrade template, but I'm running into the following error:

> TF204001: The item $/blah/blah/blah/TFSBuild.proj cannot be downloaded. Read permission is required to retrieve the content.

I can't figure out what needs this permission (my account? The build daemon? I assume the latter), nor how to grant them. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like your build agent doesn't have a permission to read from source code repository. Try adding access to the repository to the account build agent is running as.

Comment: This got me a few steps closer.

Comment: @Chris - were you able to figure out what exact problem was? it would be great if you can post your solution here. I am having the same problem.

Comment: @patil.rahulk - Sorry, but this was years ago. I can't remember what eventually worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved as follows:

1. The build agent account needs 2 permissions: Read and Label
2. You need to map you Team Collection Folder to a local folder and give the build agent account both permissions, above.
3. Make sure the templates for the builds are also there and with identical permissions.

I hope this helps.

[image: Permissions necessary for the build agent]